# Why is the canvas not found (Typesrcipt)

Tags: typescript, canvas, typeerror, addeventlistener

I try to add an eventListener to the canvas. But with the code I get this error:

```
TS2339: Property 'cvs' does not exist on type 'cvsClick'.
```

Here's the Typescript

```
cvs:HTMLCanvasElement;
ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D;

class cvsClick {

    constructor() {
        let cvs = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("background");
        let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

        this.cvs = cvs;
        this.ctx = ctx;

        this.cvs.addEventListener('click', console.log("canvas clicked"));
    }

}
new cvsClick();
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <body>
        <canvas id="background" width="780" height="480"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Maybe my EventListener is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there just declare that stuff inside the body of the class.

```
class cvsClick {
    cvs:HTMLCanvasElement;
    ctx:CanvasRenderingContext2D | null;
    constructor() {
        let cvs = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("background");
        let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

        this.cvs = cvs;
        this.ctx = ctx;

        this.cvs.addEventListener('click', console.log("canvas clicked"));
    }

}
new cvsClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, it works. The errors are gone. Still i had to change the event listener to

```
        this.cvs.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log("canvas clicked");
        });
```